# jquery: determining which option of drop down is selected

Tags: jquery

How do you determine which option is selected in a drop-down  box using jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#mySelect').val();
```

Will give the value associated with the selected option (the `value` attribute if one exists, or the text otherwise).

---

```
$('#mySelect')[0].selectedIndex;
```

Will give the index of the selected option.

---

```
$('#mySelect option:selected');
```

Will give the selected option element, from which you can grab:

```
$('#mySelect option:selected').text(); // the text
$('#mySelect option:selected').val(); // the value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="selectid">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Assuming that the user selects the second option.

Get the value of selected option

```
$("select#selectid").val();  // Returns 2
```

Get the text of the selected option

```
$("#selectid option:selected").text();  // Returns  Two
```

jsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/gpmattoo/LBRCx/

Answer (score 0):

Calling the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function with no parameters on a form element will return the current value of that element.  In the case of a `select` element (drop-down box) it will be the value of the currently selected `option` element.